# Why my title of elsarticle is in onecolumn?

Tags: titles, two-column, elsarticle

I use elsarticle document class to format my paper. However, it comes out that my title and author are in one column. My code is as follow,

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn, frontmatter]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{abstract}
    abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    Keyword1 \sep Keyword2
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Section1}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{paper.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, omit the file ending in `\bibliography`.

Answer (score 2):

The `elsarticle` class supports some two column styles, but you have to tell it which one you want. So you should add one option among `3p` or `5p`: hence you should have either

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,5p]{elsarticle}
```

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

and the result will be something like

[image]

The `3p` option supports both one and two column format, so in that case you need to specify `twocolumn`.

Note that there is no `frontmatter` document class option.